# Meteor add package not copying files

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I just installed meteor.

However, I am trying to add some packages to my app but when I run meteor add backbone it just says:

```
backbone: A minimalist client-side MVC framework
```

But my directory does not change -> no new files get added.

```
$ meteor --version
Meteor version 0.4.2 (19e42c4ec8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your **{project-path}/.meteor/local/build/app/packages/**. You should have a directory for backbone created there (containing backbone.js), ready to be used. You don't need to link the script in the HTML-file, try to call Backbone from the client console while running the app.